# Smoothness of affine variety consisting of finitely many points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes, affine-varieties, projective-varieties

Let $R$ be a commutative ring such that $X:=\mathrm{Spec}(R)=\{p\}$, where $p$ is a prime ideal. Then, obviously, the affine variety $X$ consists of one point only. However, can we decide if this variety is smooth in the Zariski topology?
Moreover, if the above ring $R$ is in addition graded, can we consider the affine variety corresponding to the underlying non-graded ring $R$ as a smooth projective variety?

Comment: You'll need to add a little more background to this post, both because it doesn't meet this site's quality standards at present and because the answer can change depending on what assumptions you take.

Comment: I tried to reformulate my question with more details.

Comment: Smoothness is a property of morphisms. Do you mean that $R$ is a $k$-algebra over some field $k$, or are you interested in regularity of $R$?

Comment: First, I am interested if $X$ is regular (non-singular or smooth).